# Constant color change using WPF

Tags: c#

Hi I created 4 rectangles and gave them a color each. I am now trying to use a button when pressed to randomly change the colors of these 4 boxes constantly (creating some kind of blinking effect). Worked out the following code but the program jams when I press the button.

Read up that `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` will be of use in this situation but not exactly sure how to use it. Looking for advice on how to go about using it. Thank you.

```
namespace testDisco
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Random r;
        Rectangle[] rects;

        SolidColorBrush blue;
        SolidColorBrush red;
        SolidColorBrush yellow;
        SolidColorBrush green;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            r = new Random();
            rects = new Rectangle[4];

            blue = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,0,232,255));
            red = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(129,56,56,255));
            yellow = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0,232,255,255));
            green = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(176,207,176,255));

            rects[0] = rect1;
            rects[1] = rect2;
            rects[2] = rect3;
            rects[3] = rect4;

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int randomNumber = r.Next(4);
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dt = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

            while (true)
            {
                rects[randomNumber].Fill = red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (true)` ಠ_ಠ so what exactly are you confused about? Why is it surprising that your program locks up?

Comment: You created a `DispatcherTimer` but then you did precisely nothing with it.  You may need to read up on the class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx).

Comment: @tnw I added while true cos I wanted it to keep changing the colors.

Comment: @Trevor. Like I was saying I am not sure on how to use it. Will read up on your link. Tnks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Slow down your loop a bit so it doesn't crash your program.

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dt = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1); //or whatever interval you want

dt.Tick += (s, e) =>
{ 
    rects[r.Next(0,3)].Fill = red;
}
```

Though that will eventually just make them all red because while you're choosing a random rectangle, you aren't choosing a random color.

Comment: Thank you. Verbally put, guess I could store a set of colors in an array and loop through them randomly to pick a color.

Comment: @user2840178 No, don't loop through them, just pick one randomly. Also, there's some weirdness going on with your rectangle array. `Rectangle[4];` declares *five* rectangles, but you only fill it with four. Don't forget that arrays are **zero-indexed**.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to take a look at the WPF animation system as defined here:

[Animation Overview - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx)

It's a bit complicated to post an answer here, but I found it a while back when I was trying to do something similar. It works better than trying to do it yourself, though. In fact, there's even a `ColorAnimation` that might do exactly what you need.

Comment: This should probably be a comment as this doesn't answer the question.